# Send the id of list menu to the route in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am developing an application using Laravel. I cannot send the id of list menu in the route. I took the id of list menu by Jquery Ajax. but It cannot be sent.

This is my app: `www.dopestylebd.com/amit`

when anyone click the list menu, so I want to make a url by the list menu's ID. But I cannot sent the id to route.

```
Route::get('/category/{id}', array(
'as' => 'postcategory',
'uses' => 'rssController@postCategory'
));
```

and JS

```
var id = $("‪#‎category‬").val();
$.post("{{ URL::route('postcategory', ['id']) }}",{id: id}, function(data)
```

Comment: Can you show your list menu html?  You probably can't get the id by using `val()`.

Comment: Yes, html list menu is working fine and on select can get the value in Js too (checked with alert()).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code.

First, your route matches `GET` calls but you're using `$.post` change either one of them so they match.

Also, because you have the `id` parameter in the URL you actually don't have to send the id as request data but rather directly put it in the URL. This is a bit cumbersome with URLs that are generated with PHP but it is possible.

```
var id = $("‪#‎category‬").val();
var url = "{{ URL::route('postcategory', ['%id']) }}" // using %id as a placeholder
$.post(url.replace('%id', id), {}, function(data){});
```